# ncaught ReferenceError:System is not defined at (index):18 dx.light.css:1 Failed to load resource:the server responded with a status of 404(Not Found)

Tags: mysql, asp.net, angular, .net-core

good day, am in the process of deploying an application on azure. the app was build on ASP.NET CORE with ANGULAR 2. But when i finished  the deployment process it shows that all succeeded -and when it load the URL just saying "Loading..." nothing comes up, then when inspect the page i get the following error "ailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and error "Uncaught Reference Error: System is not defined
at (index):18" can some one assist me what steps i can follow to resolve this matter?
URL:https://webwithaspandangulardemo.azurewebsites.net/
Thanks

Comment: Looks like the `node_modules` folder is missing. What is the build action of this folder?

Comment: hi Ryn  i tried to check that, maybe which file you would to take a look...am so confused